# UTF-8 content viewed in console different from exported results in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to use url_decode to decode lots of URL in different languages (thai / viet / chinese )

The encoded URL looks like this:

```
click_search_search=Hanmyshop&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=sp1114&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=hanmyshop&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=%C4%91%E1%BB%93ng%20h%E1%BB%93&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=Sp1114&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=nike&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=%E4%BA%8C%E6%89%8B&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=%E6%89%8B%E9%8C%B6&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=%E5%BE%8C%E8%83%8C%E5%8C%85&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=%E8%BF%AA%E5%A3%AB%E5%B0%BC&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=iphone&by=pop&order=des
```

I use below code in R to decode them

```
url=as.vector(book1$Testing.URL)

de_url=url_decode(url)

Encoding(de_url)="UTF-8"
```

Results displayed in console

```
click_search_search=Hanmyshop&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=sp1114&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=hanmyshop&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=đồng hồ&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=Sp1114&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=nike&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=二手&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=手錶&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=後背包&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=迪士尼&by=pop&order=des
click_search_search=iphone&by=pop&order=des
```

When I want to add a separate column called "Decoded.URL" in book1,

```
book1$Decoded.URL=de_url
```

After I type `View(book1)`, the results are shown differently from console. All the characters in Vietnamese or Chinese are replaced in <"U+1E3">format

I tried to use `write.table with fileEncoding="utf-8"`, doesn't help - Chinese characters are displayed correctly; Vietnamese is not. Any idea how to solve this?